# How to use textField in a Flame game?

Tags: flutter, flame

I am developing a game with flame engine. I need to open a text input (textField, textEdit or whatever its name) and ask the user his/her input (player name) as a text in my flame game. How can I do that in flame?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about doing this:

The first option is to build it yourself. This might allow for the most possible level of customization, and would involve creating a TextBoxComponent and listening to KeyboardEvents on your game. You would need to implement rendering and commands like moving the caret by yourself.

The easier option is to use the widgets overlay feature. Remember that the Flame game is just another widget in the tree, and you can compose widgets using the Flutter Stack widget. With widgets overlay you can more easily add a component that hovers on top of your flame game, that you can use to add your text input. I recommend building a simple Flutter Container with all the text input fields and labels you need and using a Widget Overlay to position that on top of your game. Please read [the docs for Widget Overlay](https://docs.flame-engine.org/1.2.0/flame/game.html#flutter-widgets-and-game-instances) for more details. Also be sure to check out a list of all the other [flame-provided widgets other than GameWidget](https://docs.flame-engine.org/1.2.0/flame/other/widgets.html) that you might want to compose with your Flutter tree.